# Куда лучше помещать всплывающие элементы в HTML?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Вот к примеру есть сайт, на нем есть какая то кнопка по нажатию на которую появляется какой то другой контент **поверх всей страницы** (что то по типу подсказки, меню и тд.).
Так куда лучше поместить этот контент, если по сути он относится ко всей странице. Может поместить туда, где и сама кнопка, или вынести в body?
Я то могу впихнуть его куда угодно, но хотел бы узнать как правильнее и логичнее будет. Подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: ну смотря что...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это модальное окно или нечто подобное, то нужно помещать самое начало или в самый конец body.

А если это всплывающая подсказка для элемента, то нужно помещать либо внутрь элемента, либо в непосредственной близости от него. Бывают разные ситуации, нужно смотреть конкретный пример.